# WWW::Mechanize in Perl, Script Gets Killed

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I have written a Perl Script which uses WWW::Mechanize to connect to a site, login and then visit a few pages inside the site. It all works good, however, when I try to visit a large number of pages, the script gets killed. I am sure this has got nothing to with the HTTP Server's Configuration and the connection limits configured. This is because, the script is running on my own site.

Here's a high level overview of my script:

```
$url="http://example.com";
$mech=WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$mech->get($url);
```

login to the site using the form fields.

Now, once I am logged in, I connect to URLs within the site as follows:

$i is the iteration counter in a for loop

```
$internal_url="http://example.com/index.php?page=$i";

$mech->get($internal_url);
```

perform some operations on the page returned ($mech->content using HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath)

now, I iterate over the for loop connecting to a different internal_url, since the value of $i is incremented in every iteration.

As I said, it all works good. However, after about 180 pages, the script gets killed.

What could be the reason? I have tried multiple times.

I even added a $mech->delete; right before the end of the FOR loop to prevent any memory leak.

However, the only issue is that the login session which was maintained by $mech would be destroyed as a result of this.

I have tried multiple times and this script always gets killed after visiting the same number of pages.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "the script gets killed"? What signal killed it? Or what exit status and error message did it exit with otherwise?

Comment: It says, KILLED and returns me to the prompt, No, SIGINT error code. However, is there a way to make it more verbose and tell the error message?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
$mech=WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->stack_depth(0);
```

OR

```
$mech=WWW::Mechanize->new(stack_depth=>0);
```

> According to the docs: Get or set the page stack depth. Use this if
>   you're doing a lot of page scraping and running out of memory.
>
> A value of 0 means "no history at all." By default, the max stack
>   depth is humongously large, effectively keeping all history.

Comment: I tried this and observed that the memory usage of perl.exe process still keeps increasing gradually with time as the script continues to extract data from pages. I did not see much improvement in the speed of execution and the memory usage with this option added. According to the document, it should allocate memory, extract data then release the memory.

Comment: Any help regarding this? My script gave an out of memory error on Windows Platform as well after running for a while. I am using the stack_depth(0) setting as well.

Comment: This may be HTML::TreeBuilder issue (I have the same in the past). Try to delete your root element each time you don't need it: `$root->delete()`

Comment: @NeonFlash you could probably accept this answer then. :)